# MySQL - How to add the occurrance number of a duplicate ID into the row

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, sql-update, windows-10

I need the Occurrence Number to be filled in. The table definition has all three columns, and the raw data has 2 columns.

```
ID | EventDate/Time | OccurrenceNumber
-----------------------------
1  | 1/11/2017      | 1
2  | 1/12/2017      | 1
3  | 1/15/2017      | 1
2  | 1/17/2017      | 2
4  | 1/18/2017      | 1
...
```

The data is presorted (raw) by Event Date (unique/time stamped) and then ID, before being read into MySQL (.csv data file), and the Occurrence Number field needs to be determined in a way that is consistent with that. (The 2nd occurrence happened 2nd in time.)

Comment: Are dates unique per group or there can be a chance of same date and same id more than once ?

Comment: The actual date field is a time stamp created by a single process (no parallels), so it's impossible the values are not unique.  The time it takes to process an entry in a lot longer than the resolution of the time stamp.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dates are unique per ID then you can use following query to get you the occurrence no. based on matching  EventDate with same table

```
select a.*,
(
  select count(*)
  from demo b
  where a.ID = b.ID
  and b.EventDate < a.EventDate // edit updated criteria 
) +1 OccurrenceNumber
from demo a
order by a.ID,a.EventDate desc
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdd2f9/1)

For update let say demo2 is the target table to update then you can write update query as

```
update demo2 b1
join (
select a.*,
(
  select count(*)
  from demo b
  where a.ID = b.ID
  and b.EventDate < a.EventDate
) +1 OccurrenceNumber
from demo a
) a1 on (b1.ID = a1.ID and b1.EventDate = a1.EventDate)
set b1.OccurrenceNumber = a1.OccurrenceNumber
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d30f0/1)

Comment: This is close.  The occurrence numbers of the duplicates are in reverse order.  ID #2 on 1/12 should be occurrence number 1.

Comment: Changing this to b.EventDate < a.EventDate works.  Once you've edited it I'll accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSmith I don't think it will fix that ordering part i am not sure, but if you say so i update my answer

Comment: I tested it.  One other thing, the code doesn't update the table. "select * from demo;" only returns two columns.

Comment: Want to update the column? , let me show add new table and update column of that table using these records let me know if sounds good?

Comment: Yes.  The actual table is very large, so it might be faster to update the column in the existing table rather than copying all the data to a new one.  But whatever works.  The script won't be ran very often.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @MikeSmith can you ask a new question with all the details related to issue  ?

Comment: This script is not working with a 40,000 row table.  If I only have 60 items it runs in less than a second, like everything else.  When I have 40,000 items, I get  a server timeout error.  It ran for 3,000 seconds.  I extended all the timeout values in the settings, and they are all larger than 3,000.  Doing a "show process list" shows a read server process is still running. (State? I had to re-log into the server.)  It was still running 3 hours later, at which point I killed it.  I'm running Windows 10, 12 GB memory, Intel i3 @ 2.5 GHz, with no other tasks running.

Comment: I'll post a new question in a couple hours when I get back.

Comment: Problem solved.  I added indexes to DateTime and ID.  The script runs correctly in 36 seconds, whereas previously it hadn't completed in 3 hours.